# SQL Server : getting all leafs from tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, tree, nodes

I have datatable which contains:

```
|Parent Key| Component Key|
```

I need to get all leafs(parent key) for a chosen component key.

For example:

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 11 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 12 |
```

for component key = 4 I want to receive

```
| 1 |
| 7 |
| 9 |
```

If selected component key is already a leaf (there is no row where component key == selected component key) I want to return only the selected component key.

Can it be done by select only ?

How to do it in the most efficient way ?

Comment: for component key = 4 it should be `2|6|9` as per your requirement that `I need to get all leafs(parent key) for choosen Component Key.`

Comment: No, 2 and 6 aren't leafs because 1 is parent for 2 and 7 is parent for 6. I need top level nodes(leafs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
DECLARE @selected INT = 4;

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT ParentKey, ComponentKey
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ComponentKey = @selected

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Table1.ParentKey, Table1.ComponentKey
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN cte ON Table1.ComponentKey = cte.ParentKey
)

SELECT ParentKey FROM cte
WHERE 
    ParentKey NOT IN (SELECT ComponentKey FROM Table1)
UNION
SELECT ParentKey FROM Table1 
WHERE 
    ParentKey = @selected
    AND ParentKey NOT IN (SELECT ComponentKey FROM Table1)
```

Replace Table1 with your table name.